# bootstrap based site appears strange in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote this site using bootstrap,

[js-projects](http://leungwensen.github.io/js-projects/)

It is what I want when opened in chrome or safari, but when I open it in firefox, it looks strange with two white strips which look like scroll bars.

could anyone help me fix this? I am new to front-end web development, and might need your patient for explaining some basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete in main.css

```
#main {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: and one more question about firefox: can I make the scroll bar disappeared like how it looks in chrome? when I clicked on some collapsed content, the page in firefox was resize because of the scroll bar.

Comment: use body{overflow-y: scroll;}

Comment: sorry to mark your answer late. I am new to ask a question here, too.